Oracle Sql Loader converting string value in csv which is "330,000.00" to table with column Capital data type number to store 330000.00
OPTIONS (SKIP=1)
LOAD DATA
INFILE *
APPEND INTO TABLE test_table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
    CAPITAL FLOAT "replace(:CAPITAL, ',', '')"
)

i tried to insert the data in table using sql loader in my csv data is "330,000.00" which i need to is 330000.00 but only 330 is getting inserted provide me solution to find the expected output

Target table:
SQL> create table test (capital number);

Table created.

Control file (contains sample data at the bottom):
load data
infile *
replace
into table test
fields terminated by whitespace
( capital "to_number(:capital, '999,999,999.99')"
)

begindata
300,000.00
24,435.53
1,374,992.02

Loading session:
SQL> $sqlldr scott/tiger@pdb1 control=test17.ctl log=test17.log

SQL*Loader: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Mon Apr 1 09:38:48 2024
Version 21.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Path used:      Conventional
Commit point reached - logical record count 2
Commit point reached - logical record count 3

Table TEST:
  3 Rows successfully loaded.

Check the log file:
  test17.log
for more information about the load.

SQL>

Result:
SQL> select * from test;

   CAPITAL
----------
    300000
  24435.53
1374992.02

SQL>


Thank you but i have tried this method also it only push 330 instead of  the value in the csv "330,000.00"

You're welcome. I don't know what exactly you tried because you didn't post it. I suggest you edit the original question and do as I did: post everything, including CREATE TABLE, complete control file, sample data, loading session and result you got.

This: FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  might be reason for what you say; comma is a field terminator and in sample value of 330,000, there's a comma which is - as we know - a terminator so it loaded 330 only. Remove that line. Re-read what I posted. Don't guess, follow code which results in valid values.
